# IntelliJ Back-end (JVM) Internal error: wrong bytecode generated. Kotlin runBlocking function

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

My function:

```
    private fun <T> callWithRetry(action: () -> T): T {
        for (i in 1..MAX_RETRIES) {
            try {
                return action()
            } catch (e: RateLimitException) {
                // Exponential Backoff
                runBlocking {
                     delay((i * i * (random.nextDouble() + .5) * 2000L).roundToLong())
                }
            }
        }
        throw Status.INTERNAL
            .withDescription("Max retries reached, please try again later.")
            .asException()
    }
```

When I try to run unit tests in IntelliJ, my program busts in this function with this error:

```
Error:Kotlin: [Internal Error] org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: wrong bytecode generated
```

Full error message here: https://justpaste.it/4vfwx

If I comment out the `delay((i * i * (random.nextDouble() + .5) * 2000L).roundToLong())`, it compiles normally.

What is the reason for this bytecode error? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=KTIJ would be a better place to report such issues.

Comment: This is most likely a Kotlin compiler bug. Can you please create an issue at http://kotl.in/issue and share a self-contained code sample to reproduce.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I created this ticket https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-2436